# How do I calculate standard deviation from a measure?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation from a hospital Average Daily Census report.  The report has by floor and by unit.  The raw data is midnight census events for each patient...hundreds every day.  I also have a filter on the report for different clinical services so the standard deviation needs to calculate "on the fly" as I change the filter.
The first picture below shows the results unfiltered.  The second shows the results with some services selected.
I have found one way to calculate deviation but it has to be from a specific field.  Since my ADC itself is calculated, this does not work.
I also saw how you can create a table (DAX?) but have not been able to get that to work and not sure it can be dynamic and calculate after filtering.
Is what I am trying to do even possible in Power BI?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are standard deviation functions in DAX. The trick is to know exactly what you are trying to calculate the standard deviation of. What is the list of values that you are trying to calculate the standard deviation of in your case?

Comment: Good morning.  It is the column ADC in the attached images.  The ADC is a calculated measure, it is not a field native to the main table in which the data resides.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but ADC is a single value for any particular filter context and the standard deviation of a single value is undefined, so I'm assuming you want wan the standard deviation over some non-singleton set. What is that set?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance!  What I am looking at is how many census events (patients in a bed at midnight) there are each day.  At one hospital the minimum number of patients in the last year for one night was 226 (daily census) and the maximum was 496.  But in my report I will be slicing by floor, unit, patient service, provider's division, provider's department, etc.  Maybe using one slicer at a time, maybe two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the standard deviation of ADC over time at a daily granularity.

If this is correct, the basic approach is to calculate the measure for each day and then take the standard deviation on that set. In DAX, this will look something like this:

```
StdDevADC =
STDEVX.S (
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( DateTable[Date], "ADCThisDate", [ADC] ),
    [ADCThisDate]
)
```

Even if this isn't exactly what you need, it should give you an idea of how to approach this. You need to calculate `[ADC]` for each element of the dimension you want to take the standard deviation over and then use the iterator version of the Standard Deviation function to calculate over that table/list you just calculated.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that.  It makes sense on "paper".  :-)